# how do i add items in combobox?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, combobox

i am having a problem. How do i add items in comboBox?

I already tried this code:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add("--Dates--");
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

but it is cannot add the items in comboBox when i run the program.

Here is the code:

```
public partial class Trans : Form
    {
        string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=..\db1.accdb";

        private const int CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON = 0x200;

        private Choices _choice;

        private DataSet _ds = new DataSet();

        private List<DateTime> _startDate = new List<DateTime>();
        private List<DateTime> _endDate = new List<DateTime>();

        int startDate;
        int endDate;

        public Trans()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Trans(Choices _choice)
            : this()
        {
            this._choice = _choice;
        }

        private void Trans_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            startDate = (int)DateTime.Today.AddYears(5).Subtract(DateTime.Today).TotalDays + 1;
            endDate = (int)DateTime.Today.AddYears(5).Subtract(DateTime.Today).TotalDays + 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < startDate; i++)
            {
                _startDate.Add(DateTime.Today.AddDays(i));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < endDate; i++)
            {
                _endDate.Add(DateTime.Today.AddDays(i));
            }

            StartDateCollection(sender, e);

            this.dataGridView1.Columns["ID"].Visible = false;
            this.dataGridView1.Sort(this.dataGridView1.Columns["Times"], System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending);
            this.label3.Text = "Welcome, " + UserInformation.CurrentLoggedInUser + " " + " " + "-" + " " + " " + UserInformation.CurrentLoggedInUserType;
            this.label3.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

            dataGridView1.RowPostPaint += new DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventHandler(this.SetRowNumber);
            dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
        }

        private void ViewDatabase(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string query = "SELECT [ProductCode], [Quantity], [Description], [SubTotal], [Total], [IssuedBy], [To], [Dates], [Times] FROM [TransRecord]";

                conn.Open();

                using (OleDbDataAdapter _adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn))
                {
                    _ds.Clear();
                    _adapter.Fill(_ds, "TransRecord");
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
                    dataGridView1.Refresh();
                }

                dataGridView1.DataSource = _ds.Tables[0];

                conn.Close();
            }
        }

        private void SetRowNumber(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
        {
            var grid = sender as DataGridView;
            var rowIdx = (e.RowIndex + 1).ToString();

            var centerFormat = new StringFormat()
            {
                Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
                LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
            };

            var headerBounds = new Rectangle(e.RowBounds.Left, e.RowBounds.Top, grid.RowHeadersWidth, e.RowBounds.Height);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(rowIdx, this.Font, SystemBrushes.ControlText, headerBounds, centerFormat);
        }

        private void StartDateCollection(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.DataSource = _startDate;
            comboBox1.FormatString = "M/dd/yyyy";
            comboBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
        }

        private void StartDateCollection_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime comboBox1_SelectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(comboBox1.SelectedValue);
            List<DateTime> tempDate = _endDate.Where(d => d > comboBox1_SelectedDate).ToList<DateTime>();
            comboBox2.DataSource = tempDate;
            comboBox2.FormatString = "M/dd/yyyy";
            comboBox2.FormattingEnabled = true;
        }
```

(.... Other codes)

I put the Items.Add in the StartDateCollection function, but it is not appear the string that i add in, only appear the dates.

How do i fix that?

Thanks.

Or, i would like to have from first date transaction record.

Example: I have transaction record on this day `24 September 2013`, but when i open the program at tomorrow, i cannot open the transaction record on `24 September 2013`, because the date `24 September 2013` already disappeared. I want to the combobox items are displaying from the first date of the transaction record.

I appreciate your answer
Thank you so much!

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

As you can see from the picture above, the Start Date in ComboBox are `Date`, i want to make a `---Dates---` before the `Date` are shown. So it will be something like this (in comboBox)
---Dates---
9/24/2013
9/25/2013
......
(And so on)

Comment: write comboBox2.DataBind() after this comboBox2.FormattingEnabled = true;

Comment: there is no .DataBind() sir

Comment: you are using asp.net or windows form ?

Comment: windows forms, i already tagged winForms

Comment: I tried your combobox binding code and it working fine check my sample code in my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need your first item in combo box should be some generic text for example  "Select date" or something so this can be on approach.

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<DateTime> lstDate = new List<DateTime>();
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            lstDate.Add(dt);
        }

        List<string> lstDataSource = lstDate.Select(a => a.ToString("M/dd/yyyy")).ToList();
        lstDataSource.Insert(0, "---Select Date---");
        comboBox1.DataSource = lstDataSource;            
        comboBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<DateTime> lstDate = new List<DateTime>();
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        {
            lstDate.Add(dt);
        }

        comboBox1.DataSource = lstDate;
        comboBox1.FormatString = "M/dd/yyyy";
        comboBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;

    }
```

it is adding dates in combo box

[image]

Comment: Yeah, i already did that sir, but this is not what i want, please refer to the question again, i already include the screenshot. Thanks

Comment: Your question still not clear, you are saying "So it will be something like this (in comboBox) ---Dates--- 9/24/2013 9/25/2013 ...... (And so on)" so it is displaying in your "Start Date" combo as you have shown in screen shot

Comment: I mean, when i run the program. ComboBox will display as follow:
First item: ---Dates---, Second item and third and so on: (display a date)

Comment: so you need combo box first item should be text for example "---Dates---" and then onward all dates .. am I correct ?

Comment: No prob .. always focus on main goal not entire things :)